# Error when trying to start Centos 7 installer

Tags: installation, centos-7

I am getting an error, when trying to install Centos... I wasn't able to find the log file the installer was talking about, and this is why i was forced to record with my mobile phone... Link to video: http://www.mediafire.com/watch/03mt7gcqiedb1n6/install_problems.mp4 Please help!!

This error happened after i used dban to format my hard-drives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Rufus is a broken usb creator tool... I used Win 32 Disk Imager instead.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the origin of your problem and how you fixed it? It sounds like the problem wasn't what you thought it was so your solution doesn't make any sense.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with Rufus.

Comment: It's written on the centos wiki, that Rufus is broken when It comes to centos.